# Limit Computation of $(e^x+x)^{1/x}$ as $x$ approaches zero

Tags: limits

I need help computing the limit of $(e^x+x)^{1/x}$ as $x$ approaches zero. I just need help getting started with the computation. The only way I can think of rearranging the equation is distributing the $1/x$.

Comment: But you can’t distribute the $1/x$: $(a+b)^c\ne a^c+b^c$. And you **really** ought to read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) on accepting answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This limit is a $1^\infty$ indeterminate form, and there’s a standard method for attacking such limits. Let $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(e^x+x\right)^{1/x}\;.$$ The log function is continuous, so

$$\begin{align*}
\ln L&=\ln\lim_{x\to 0}\left(e^x+x\right)^{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(e^x+x\right)^{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(e^x+x\right)}x\;.
\end{align*}$$

Here the numerator and denominator both tend to $0$ as $x\to 0$, so you can apply l’Hospital’s rule.

Comment: So then it would be the limit of (e^x+1)/(e^x+x) as x goes to zero?

Comment: @Lizi: Yes. He said that nicely.

Comment: @Lizi: As Babak says, yes; and that limit is a nice easy one. Oh, and thank you for going back and accepting some of the old answers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Should the first line be $\ln \lim\ldots$, not $\ln\lim\ln\ldots$?

Comment: @Daryl: It should indeed; that was a copy-paste error during editing. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Very frequently, L'Hospital's rule is overkill and may be replaced by the more elementary recognition and calculation of some derivative. This is the case here:
setting
$$f(x)=\ln(e^x+x),$$
we find immediately
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}x=f'(0)=2.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval: Perfectly true. In practice, however, it’s likely to be quicker to apply the mechanical procedure, especially in the likely event that one took the log with that procedure in mind. (It’s a useful point, though, and even at this late date you might consider posting it as another answer; if you did so and left me a note, I’d certainly upvote it.)

Answer (score 8):

Without using l'Hopital, you may do this:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} (e^x + x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} (e^x(1 + \frac{x}{e^x}))^{\frac{1}{x}}=$$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} e (1 + \frac{x}{e^x})^{\frac{1}{x}}= e \lim_{x\to 0} \big[(1 + \frac{x}{e^x})^{\frac{e^x}{x}}\big]^\frac{1}{e^x}=$$
$$ = e \big[\lim_{x\to 0} (1 + \frac{x}{e^x})^{\frac{e^x}{x}}\big]^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^x}}= e \cdot e^1 = e^2.$$

Use has been made of the facts that:

If $u(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, then $$(1+u(x))^{\frac{1}{u(x)}} \to e,$$
and $$\lim u(x) ^{v(x)} = \big(\lim u(x) \big)^{\lim v(x)},$$
provided that the individual limits exist.

Answer (score 5):

You might start by taking the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Take the logarithm and rewrite the limit to use L'Hopital. The result ends up being $e^2$.
What I mean is writing it as
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(x+e^x)}{x} \right)$$

It is now of $0/0$, so you can use L'Hopital.

**Alternative hint:**
Possibly rewrite it as a series and notice the higher order terms go to $0$. Thus, you can approximate the limit as just the first term of the Taylor Series, which is just $e^2$.