# Limit of a Function: $ \lim_{x \to 0}\ (e^x + x)^ {\large \frac {1} {x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of the following function which consists of an exponential and algebraic expression? $$ \lim_{x \to 0}\ (e^x + x)^ {\large \frac {1} {x}}\;\;?$$

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination "Should be"? How can the answer depend on $x$ when we are asked to take the limit $x \to 0$?!

Comment: $e^2$ using log and L'Hospital

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit Computation of $(e^x+x)^{1/x}$ as $x$ approaches zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262508/limit-computation-of-exx1-x-as-x-approaches-zero)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, take the logarithm and look at $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x + x)}{x}$.

Apply L'Hopital's rule to get $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x + x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x + 1}{e^x + x} = 2$.

Hence $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}(e^x + x)^\frac{1}{x} = \exp(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x + x)}{x}) = \exp(2) = e^2$.

Comment: It took me 1 month to finally understand L'Hospital rule. Thanks!

Comment: Very frequently, L'Hospital's rule is overkill and may be replaced by the more elementary recognition and calculation of some derivative. This is the case here:
setting
$$f(x)=\ln(e^x+x),$$
we find immediately
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}x=f'(0)=2.$$

Answer (score 4):

Using [L'Hôpital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule),
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(e^x+x\right)^{1/x} &=& \exp\left\{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ \ln \left[\left(e^x+x\right)^{1/x}\right]\right\} \\
&=& \exp\left[\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln \left(e^x+x\right)}{x}\right] \\
&=& \exp\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}\right) \\
&=& e^2
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: The jump from the second line to the third one requires, I think, a thorough justification

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hôpital's_rule

Answer (score 3):

$$
\large \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\ (e^x + x)^ \frac {1} {x} &= e \; \lim_{x \to 0}\ \left (1 + \frac{x}{e^x} \right )^ {\frac {1} {x}}\\ 
 &= e \; \lim_{x \to 0}\ \left (\left (1 + \frac{x}{e^x} \right )^ {\frac {1}{\frac x{e^x}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{e^x}}\\ 
 &= e e = e^2\\
\end{align*} 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that when $\alpha(x)$ is so small when $x\to\infty$, then we have $$a^{\alpha(x)}-1\sim\alpha(x)\ln(a)$$ Use this fact and set $a=e, \alpha(x)=x$, so have the limit $e^2$.

Comment: Nice observation! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Above fact has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} &=& \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln (e^x + x)}\\
&=& \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln (e^x(1 + xe^{-1}))} \\
&=& \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln e^x} e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln (1 + xe^{-x})}\\
&=& e \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln (1 + xe^{-x})}
\end{eqnarray}
Since $y \mapsto \ln(1+y)$ is differentiable at zero, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|y|<\delta$, then $|\ln(1+y)-y|\leq \epsilon |y|$. This gives $|\ln (1 + xe^{-x})-x e^{-x}| \leq \epsilon |x| e^{-x}$, or equivalently, $|\frac{1}{x}\ln (1 + xe^{-x})-e^{-x}| \leq \epsilon  e^{-x}$, from which it follows that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln (1 + xe^{-x}) = 1$, from which we obtain $\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^2$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ (e^x + x)^ \frac {1} {x} &=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ (1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots + x)^ \frac {1} {x}\\ &=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ (1+2x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots )^ \frac {1} {x}=e^2\end{align}$$Note that since $x \to 0$ we can assume $\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots =0$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{u \to 0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}{2}}=e^2$$ where $u=2x.$

Alternatively note that  $$\lim_{x \to 0}(1+2x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots )^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{u \to 0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{u}{x}]} = \exp{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{u}{x}}=e^2$$
 where $u=2x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$ and

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{u}{x} &=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots}{x}\\ &=\lim_{x \to 0}[2+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots]\\ &= 2\end{align}$$

I personally like the first method because with some logical fact the given limit reduces to a smooth limit. Some people dislike the first method though it is not wrong. If anybody want to avoid the logical fact and wanna solve the problem only with mathematical tools he/she may solve the problem in the second method.

Comment: You need to explain why the final limit is $e^2$.

Comment: This doesn't convince me.

Comment: @PatrickLi : I think you will be convinced with the second method that I just add with my answer.