# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0}\ (e^x+x)^{1/x}$ with L'Hopital's rule, not standard limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ (e^x+x)^{1/x}$$
I need to solve it using L'Hopital's rule.
I suppose, answer is $e^2$, but I'm not sure.
Thank you.

Comment: isn't the limit simply $e + 1$ by substitution?

Comment: Are you sure $x\to 1$?

Comment: you probably mean $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Should the limit point be $0$?

Comment: I think, I can use $ln$ and get quotient

Comment: I'm sorry, →0

Comment: "You are sorry"...yet you wrote $\;x\to1\;$ once again...!

Comment: Of course $0$, I'm sorry again. I fixed it in the question

Comment: It's ok just keep it the way it is... you got two answers one for $x\rightarrow 1$ and one for $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Hah, nice to see it

Comment: Why would you impose the use of L'Hopital's rule, if some more elementary solution is available? + [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Duplicate: [Limit of a Function: $ \lim_{x \to 0}\ (e^x + x)^ {\large \frac {1} {x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit is as $x\rightarrow 0$ (I see you edit) then you can use the fact that $\ln$ and $\exp$ are continuous to get that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ (e^x+x)^\dfrac{1}{x} = L$$

Iff

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x} = \ln (L)$$

Now you can use the l'hopital rule

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}=\frac{2}{1}=2$$

Therefore $\ln(L)=2$ and so $L=e^2$.

Comment: Thank you. It's true

Comment: Very frequently, L'Hospital's rule is overkill and may be replaced by the more elementary recognition and calculation of some derivative. This is the case here:
setting
$$f(x)=\ln(e^x+x),$$
we find immediately
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}x=f'(0)=2.$$

Answer (score 3):

You can't use L'Hospital here as this is not one of the forms that allow it:

$$(e^x+x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(e^x+x)}\xrightarrow[x\to1]{}e^{\frac11\log(e+1)}=e+1$$

Comment: I think it should be $$e^{\frac1x\log(e^x+x)}\xrightarrow[x\to1]{}e^{\frac11\frac{1+1}{1}}=e^2$$

Comment: @user I can't see why: $\;e^x+x\to e+1\;$ if $\;x\to 1\;$ ...You seem to have deleted the logarithm in the exponent...

Comment: I was assuming you have applied l'Hospital.

Comment: @user Not at all. I even wrote that L'Hospital cannot be used here.

Comment: But the limit is as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @user As you can read in the comments, it was **not** so at first. In fact, it was $\;x\to 1\;$ a good time after the question was posted and I answered. It changed afterwards.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I didn’t noticed all that! Bye